# What does "in a blur" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, slang

What does "in a blur" mean in the sentence below? Is it a slang? Does it mean "very fast"?

> "I grinned as I counted more quickly and ran the numbers together in a blur."

[Source](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=r9-HAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT17&ots=wbsY1MySh-&dq=I%20grinned%20as%20I%20counted%20more%20Quickly%20and%20Ran%20the%20Numbers%20together%20in%20a%20blur&pg=PT17#v=onepage&q=I%20grinned%20as%20I%20counted%20more%20Quickly%20and%20Ran%20the%20Numbers%20together%20in%20a%20blur&f=false): Counting Stars (By David Almond)

Comment: Imagine a picture were taken of you using an old-timey camera with a slow shutter speed.  If you were moving quickly the image would be blurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in this context it does mean very fast, so fast that you are moving too quickly for the world around you.